# Unable to find partial in a component test

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I have a component test that is failing because it can't find a partial that the template is rendering. The specific error is "Assertion Failed: Unable to find partial with name 'components/activity-list-item-content'."

My test file is basically the default generated by ember-cli:

```
import {
  moduleForComponent,
  test
} from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForComponent('activity-list-item', 'ActivityListComponent', {
  // specify the other units that are required for this test
  needs: ['helper:format-date']
});

test('it renders', function() {
  expect(2);

  // creates the component instance
  var component = this.subject();
  equal(component._state, 'preRender');

  // appends the component to the page
  this.append();
  equal(component._state, 'inDOM');
});
```

and the component template that looks like this:

```
{{#if activity.momentId}}
  {{#link-to 'moment' momentId class='close-dropdown'}}
    {{partial 'components/activity-list-item-content'}}
  {{/link-to}}
{{else}}
  {{partial 'components/activity-list-item-content'}}
{{/if}}
```

My application is working fine without any errors, so I'm wondering if it's something missing from my test setup. I've also tried adding it to the `needs` array and get the same error:

```
needs: ['helper:format-date', 'template:components/-activity-list-item-content']
```

How do I get my tests to find the partial?

**Update**

@GJK pointed out that the partial name should start with an underscore instead of a dash. If I make that change, the test passes, however I get a depcrecation warning in the console that says:

> DEPRECATION: Modules should not contain underscores. Attempted to lookup "myapp-ember/templates/components/-activity-list-item-content" which was not found. Please rename "myapp-ember/templates/components/_activity-list-item-content" to "myapp-ember/templates/components/-activity-list-item-content" instead.

Comment: [Partial names must start with an underscore](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper) (not a dash). Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: @GJK if I change to an underscore, I get this error: DEPRECATION: Modules should not contain underscores. Attempted to lookup "myapp-ember/templates/components/-activity-list-item-content" which was not found. Please rename "myapp-ember/templates/components/_activity-list-item-content" to "myapp-ember/templates/components/-activity-list-item-content" instead.

Comment: It looks like maybe an incompatibility with ember-cli? https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2097

Comment: Considering the [example](http://www.ember-cli.com/#resolving-from-template-helpers) in the docs (ember-cli), why not name the partials without hyphens or underscores?

Comment: @PatsyIssa that did the trick, thanks! I wonder why they suggest that partials need to start with a hyphen or underscore when it's not really required.

Comment: OP and @GJK ember-cli want's them to start with a hyphen instead of an underscore. Everything in ember cli is with hyphens instead of underscores. I believe prefixing it is just a convention so that when someone else looks at the code they realize it's a partial

Answer (score 0):

Found this issue: https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/issues/110

The current workaround is:

```
import resolver from '../../helpers/resolver';

moduleForComponent('some-other-thing', 'component:some-other-thing', {
  needs: ['component:some-thing'],

  setup: function() {
    this.container.register('template:path/to/partial', 
           resolver.resolve('template:path/to/-partial'));
  }
});
```